# Using Local Storage to save the state of collapse menu and the colour of selected menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hey Guys I have a Side menu Bar which opens and closes on pressing a toggle icon, but the menu bar collapses when the page refreshes ( or when another menu is pressed )and the colour of the selected menu also disappears. I know local storage is a good way to keep the state. I tried many times, but couldn't figure out a method. Any help is very much appreciated.  Posted below is my working code so far without the local storage. Thank you for your time.

```js
/*===== EXPANDER MENU  =====*/
const showMenu = (toggleId, navbarId, bodyId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    navbar = document.getElementById(navbarId),
    bodypadding = document.getElementById(bodyId)

  if (toggle && navbar) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      navbar.classList.toggle('expander')

      bodypadding.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    })
  }
}
showMenu('nav-toggle', 'navbar', 'body-pd')

/*===== LINK ACTIVE  =====*/
const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

function colorLink() {
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
  this.classList.add('active')
}
linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))


/*===== COLLAPSE MENU  =====*/
const linkCollapse = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse__link')
var i

for (i = 0; i < linkCollapse.length; i++) {
  linkCollapse[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const collapseMenu = this.nextElementSibling
    collapseMenu.classList.toggle('showCollapse')

    const rotate = collapseMenu.previousElementSibling
    rotate.classList.toggle('rotate')
  })
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap");

/*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/

:root {
  --nav-width: 92px;
  /*===== Colores =====*/
  --first-color: #016FFE;
  --bg-color: #1C1F2B;
  --sub-color: #B6CEFC;
  --white-color: #FFF;
  /*===== Fuente y tipografia =====*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  --small-font-size: .875rem;
  /*===== z index =====*/
  --z-fixed: 100;
}


/*===== BASE =====*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem 0 0 6.75rem;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .5s;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*===== l NAV =====*/

.l-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 2rem;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
}


/*===== NAV =====*/

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav__brand {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.nav__toggle {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .75rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.nav__name {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
}


/*Expander menu*/

.expander {
  width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 9.25rem);
}


/*Add padding body*/

.body-pd {
  padding: 2rem 0 0 16rem;
}


/*Active links menu*/

.active {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*===== COLLAPSE =====*/

.collapse {
  grid-template-columns: 20px max-content 1fr;
}

.collapse__link {
  justify-self: flex-end;
  transition: .5s;
}

.collapse__menu {
  display: none;
  padding: .75rem 2.25rem;
}

.collapse__sublink {
  color: var(--sub-color);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
}

.collapse__sublink:hover {
  color: var(--white-color);
}


/*Show collapse*/

.showCollapse {
  display: block;
}


/*Rotate icon*/

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- ===== CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Sidebar sub menus</title>
</head>


<body id="body-pd">



  <div class="l-navbar" id="navbar">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div>
        <div class="nav__brand">
          <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle"></ion-icon>


        </div>
        <div class="nav__list">
          <a href="template.html" class="nav__link active">
            <ion-icon name="home-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
          <a href="trial5.html" class="nav__link">
            <ion-icon name="bulb-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Trailer Lights</span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__link collapse">
            <ion-icon name="videocam" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Video Feed</span>

            <ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" class="collapse__link"></ion-icon>

            <ul class="collapse__menu">
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Data</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Group</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Members</a>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <a href="#" class="nav__link">
            <ion-icon name="pie-chart-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Analytics</span>
          </a>
          <div class="nav__link collapse">
            <ion-icon name="people-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Team</span>

            <ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" class="collapse__link"></ion-icon>

            <ul class="collapse__menu">
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Data</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Group</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Members</a>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <ion-icon name="log-out-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
        <span class="nav__name">Log Out</span>



      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>



  <!-- ===== IONICONS ===== -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

  <!-- ===== MAIN JS ===== -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>





</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `forEach` loop where you add the event listeners, I added a data attribute to store an "index"  for each `.nav__link`. That is what is to be stored in `localStorage` on click.

In the same loop, if there is an "index' stored, add the `active` class and remove everywhere else.

I also fixed a `Deprecated script` warning that you had about `ionicon`.
;)

```js
/*===== EXPANDER MENU  =====*/
const showMenu = (toggleId, navbarId, bodyId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    navbar = document.getElementById(navbarId),
    bodypadding = document.getElementById(bodyId)

  if (toggle && navbar) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      navbar.classList.toggle('expander')

      bodypadding.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    })
  }
}
showMenu('nav-toggle', 'navbar', 'body-pd')

/*===== LINK ACTIVE  =====*/
const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

function colorLink() {
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
  this.classList.add('active')
  
  // Added this to read data attribute
  let this_index = this.getAttribute("data-nav_link_index")
  //localStorage.setItem("active_nav_link", this_index) // Commeneted here because SO disallow it and throws errors
}
linkColor.forEach((l,i) => {
  l.addEventListener('click', colorLink);
  
  // Added this to set data attribute
  l.setAttribute("data-nav_link_index", i);
  
  // Added this to add the active class
  // Commeneted here because SO disallow it and throws errors
  /*
  if(localStorage.getItem("active_nav_link")==i){
    l.classList.add("active");
  }else if(localStorage.getItem("active_nav_link")!==null){
    l.classList.remove("active");
  }
  */
})


/*===== COLLAPSE MENU  =====*/
const linkCollapse = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse__link')
var i

for (i = 0; i < linkCollapse.length; i++) {
  linkCollapse[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const collapseMenu = this.nextElementSibling
    collapseMenu.classList.toggle('showCollapse')

    const rotate = collapseMenu.previousElementSibling
    rotate.classList.toggle('rotate')
  })
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap");

/*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/

:root {
  --nav-width: 92px;
  /*===== Colores =====*/
  --first-color: #016FFE;
  --bg-color: #1C1F2B;
  --sub-color: #B6CEFC;
  --white-color: #FFF;
  /*===== Fuente y tipografia =====*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  --small-font-size: .875rem;
  /*===== z index =====*/
  --z-fixed: 100;
}


/*===== BASE =====*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem 0 0 6.75rem;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .5s;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*===== l NAV =====*/

.l-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 2rem;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
}


/*===== NAV =====*/

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav__brand {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.nav__toggle {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .75rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.nav__name {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
}


/*Expander menu*/

.expander {
  width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 9.25rem);
}


/*Add padding body*/

.body-pd {
  padding: 2rem 0 0 16rem;
}


/*Active links menu*/

.active {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*===== COLLAPSE =====*/

.collapse {
  grid-template-columns: 20px max-content 1fr;
}

.collapse__link {
  justify-self: flex-end;
  transition: .5s;
}

.collapse__menu {
  display: none;
  padding: .75rem 2.25rem;
}

.collapse__sublink {
  color: var(--sub-color);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
}

.collapse__sublink:hover {
  color: var(--white-color);
}


/*Show collapse*/

.showCollapse {
  display: block;
}


/*Rotate icon*/

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- ===== CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Sidebar sub menus</title>
</head>


<body id="body-pd">



  <div class="l-navbar" id="navbar">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div>
        <div class="nav__brand">
          <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle"></ion-icon>


        </div>
        <div class="nav__list">
          <a href="template.html" class="nav__link active">
            <ion-icon name="home-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
          <a href="trial5.html" class="nav__link">
            <ion-icon name="bulb-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Trailer Lights</span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__link collapse">
            <ion-icon name="videocam" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Video Feed</span>

            <ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" class="collapse__link"></ion-icon>

            <ul class="collapse__menu">
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Data</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Group</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Members</a>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <a href="#" class="nav__link">
            <ion-icon name="pie-chart-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Analytics</span>
          </a>
          <div class="nav__link collapse">
            <ion-icon name="people-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
            <span class="nav__name">Team</span>

            <ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" class="collapse__link"></ion-icon>

            <ul class="collapse__menu">
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Data</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Group</a>
              <a href="#" class="collapse__sublink">Members</a>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <ion-icon name="log-out-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
        <span class="nav__name">Log Out</span>



      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>



  <!-- ===== IONICONS ===== -->
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

  <!-- ===== MAIN JS ===== -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>





</body>


</html>
```

`localStorage` is not allowed in SO snippets... So have a look at my [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KKgRNjV?editors=0010)

---

**EDIT**

About the expanded/collapsed state of the menu, you just have to store another item...

```
/*===== EXPANDER MENU  =====*/

// Have the menu state in a variable
let menu_expanded = Boolean(localStorage.getItem("expanded"));

const showMenu = (toggleId, navbarId, bodyId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    navbar = document.getElementById(navbarId),
    bodypadding = document.getElementById(bodyId)
    
  if (toggle && navbar) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      
      // Toggle the variable
      menu_expanded = !menu_expanded
      
      // Use the variable in both toggle method
      navbar.classList.toggle('expander', menu_expanded)
      bodypadding.classList.toggle('body-pd', menu_expanded)
      
      // Save to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("expanded", (menu_expanded)?"true":"false")
    })
  }
}
showMenu('nav-toggle', 'navbar', 'body-pd')
```

Comment: Hey !! Thank you so much for your answer!!! The colour of the menus now works perfectly !! But the menu collapses every time the page refreshes. Is there any way to solve that? Thanks Heaps !!!!

Comment: You can save another localStorage item for the state of the menu... Something like `expanded` with a true/false value.

Comment: So same thing... If there is an `expanded` item and is true, trigger a `.nav-toggle` click.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for your reply!!!. Unfortunately i barely know JavaScript coding and i am very new to this :( . sorry for asking much.  I got this code from a online source.

Comment: I edited with the code to save the menu state.

Comment: Hey Thank you for replying !! But it doesn't seem to work :( Is it because the get item is "expanded" instead of expander?